# Pickle dump an object referencing a module

Tags: python, module, pickle

I would like to pickle-dump an object like this:

```
import module_A
import module_B

class SomeClass(object):
  def __init__(self, the_module):
    self.module = the_module
    self.some_other_members = whatever

x = SomeClass(module_A)
```

It is not allowed and the error is that I cannot dump a module. In this case I'm not interested in actually dumping the module. However, which module the object is using matters. So I would like to dump some identifier of the module such that on `__setstate__` I can point `self.module` to the right module. What kind of identifiers should I use such that on `__setstate__` I can find the right module by that identifier? There may be many possible modules and the class `SomeClass` does now know which of them are there.

UPDATE:

Sorry the error message we found is when we were using `cPickle`. The ordinary `pickle` does not have this problem, and as Mike mentioned, `dill` supports pickling modules too. The final solution I'm using is the one given here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-July/021959.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do exactly what you want with `dill`, which provides better serialization than `pickle`.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import numpy
>>>
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> class SomeClass(object):
...   def __init__(self, module):
...     self.module = module
...     self.other = lambda x: numpy.arange(3)
... 
>>> # save the class instance
>>> x = SomeClass(math)
>>> _x = dill.dumps(x)
>>>
>>> # delete a bunch of stuff
>>> del SomeClass 
>>> del math
>>> import sys
>>> del sys.modules['math']
>>> del x
>>>
>>> # unpickle
>>> x = dill.loads(_x)
>>> x.module
>>> x.module.sin(x.other(0)[0])
0.0
```

Comment: BTW: I'm the `dill` author, so if you find it doesn't work for your case, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I'm actually using the solution in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-July/021959.html, but it is nice to know that dill can do this. Is it using the same technique? By the way, I found that the serialized strings from dill protocol 2 is a few times larger than cPickle protocol 2. Is there a way to reduce the size in dill dumps but maintain the load speed?

Comment: The link you provide is one of the ways `dill` serializes a module.  For certain objects (like classes, functions, and methods), you can change what `dill` pickles by changing the `dill.settings`.  `dill.settings['byref'] = True` will more closely mimic what `cPickle` is doing. `dill.settings['recurse'] = True` will include only the relevant dependencies from `globals`, while the default is to take everything.  The pickles are longer in general because to handle more cases, one needs to pickle more instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Mike. This is very helpful. I'm going to unpickle a large amount of data, and I care about file size and unpickling time. However most of my data are in large numpy matrices, in that case does dill protocol 2 performs similar with cPickle protocol 2?

Comment: For `numpy` objects, the best choice is to use the `topickle` (?) method built-in to `numpy`… the pickles from that will be the smallest possible.  Both `klepto` and `joblib` can also pickle `numpy` arrays from multiple files, and can use numpy's minimal pickle.  I think `dill` uses the longer version (but I am not 100% sure).

Answer (score 0):

Well, hardly a total answer, but when I took a look at a module I set on a 'dummy', a test object, I get.

```
print dummy.module.__file__
```

output

```
'lib/utils.pyc'
```

and some inspection:

```
>>> type(dummy.module)
<type 'module'>
>>> type(dummy.module.__file__)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Maybe you can save "lib/utils" from the above (during your __getstate__) and then do the appropriate **import** incantations to get your module back during __setstate__?

You dont have to bother with **import** at all, if the module is already loaded:

```
dummy.module2 = sys.modules["lib.utils"]
```